# elasticsearch: distinct token matching

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

tl;dr: **I want to have a query that matches every token once at max**

Given I have an elasticsearch index with the following words:

`["stackoverflow", "overflow", "awesome", "some"]`

Is there any elasticsearch query, that matches
`"stackoverflow"` and `"awesome"` on the sentence "**stackoverflow** community is **awesome**" and doesn't match `"overflow"` and `"some"`?

I can't do it with score only, because there's also a misspelling detection included.

What I'm searching for is something like a consuming matching. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything suitable so far :(

Thanks!

---

more details:

The indexed documents look like this

```
{"name": "stackoverflow",
 "type": "brand"},
{"name": "awesome",
 "type": "descriptor"},
{"name": "overflow",
 "type": "brand"},
{"name": "some",
 "type": "descriptor"}
```

My query looks like this:

```
{
  "min_score": 1,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "stakoverflow community is awesom",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "rescore": {
    "window_size": 10,
    "query": {
      "rescore_query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "stakoverflow community is awesom"
        }
      },
        "query_weight": 0.9,
        "rescore_query_weight": 1.1
    }
  }
}
```

So I basically try to catch misspellings in the first query and prefer non-misspelling in the rescore.

**What I'd like to achieve:**

For each token, I'd like to have at most 1 match:

```
INPUT  stakoverflow  community   is       awesom
OUTPUT stackoverflow <nothing>  <nothing> awesome
```

My problem is, that I also get **overflow** and **some** returned. Overflow might even have a better score than awesome, because its not a misspelling.

Comment: Without more detail on your schema, sample docs and queries that you've tried it will be hard for anyone to provide meaningful answers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, John! I thought it might be a good idea to keep the problem description as short as possible. Obviously that was too short ;) I've added more details to the question. I hope, it's clearer now?